# LAN service discovery

Tags: service, udp, codenameone

I need to do a simple service discovery in Codename1, to allow clients
running on the same LAN to discover one another.  The natural
approach would be broadcast UDP packets, but they seem to be
unsupported.   Another approach, a lot less desirable, would
be to go outside the lan and implement a web service.

Suggestions would be welcomed.  For the moment, I'm only
interested in Android.

Answer (score 0):

We don't support that. You can use a native interface which would be pretty easy to implement in Android as you would implement it in Java.

We already have two cn1libs that implement [TCP](https://github.com/shannah/CN1Sockets) and [websockets](https://github.com/shannah/cn1-websockets) so you can get a general idea of how to do something like that from there. Although I'm guessing what you would need could be far simpler.